# Solve $f'(x)=(x+a)^2f(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm using the method of characteristics to solve a PDE and I'm stuck with a simple ODE. I am trying to solve 
$$f'(x)=(x+a)^2f(x)$$
where $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Where can I find the method to solve this kind of ODE or better yet can someone show me here? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a separable ODE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\frac {dy}{dx} = (x+a)^2 y$

This is a separable diff eq

$\int \frac {dy}{y} = \int (x+a)^2 \ dx\\
\ln y = \frac 13 (x+a)^3  + C\\
y = Ce^{\frac {(x+a)^3}{3}}$

Answer (score 1):

$$(x-a)^2= {f'(x)\over f(x)} = (\ln(f(x)))'$$

So $$(x-a)^3/3 = \ln (f(x))$$